# Error while installing bedtools via cygwin commands: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to install the [bedtools](http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/installation.html) v2.27.0 via Cygwin. Here are the commands I've tried:

```
$ wget https://github.com/arq5x/bedtools2/releases/download/v2.27.0/bedtools-2.27.0.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf bedtools-2.27.0.tar.gz
$ cd bedtools2
$ make
```

when running the last command, I get the following error:

```
*fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory  
*#include <zlib.h>*  
^  
compilation terminated.  
make[1]: *** [Makefile:37: ../../../obj//FileRecordMgr.o] Error 1  
make: *** [Makefile:187: src/utils/FileRecordTools] Error 2*
```

I tried downloading the `libz` package using the following command:

```
$ apt-cyg install libz-dev
```

but it didn't work. I got the following error:

```
Unable to locate package libz-dev
```

Note that I'm using Cygwin terminal on windows (64-bit machine). Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To install packages use `cygwin setup`, or at least find the right package name before using `apt-cyg`

To find the package containing zlib.h header:

```
$ cygcheck -p include/zlib.h
Found 10 matches for include/zlib.h
...
zlib-devel-1.2.11-1 - zlib-devel: gzip de/compression library (development)
..
```

So you need to install `zlib-devel`

Comment: Thanks...this was useful! I downloaded zlib-devel, and it partly worked. However, I got another error: coverageFile.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void CoverageFile::giveFinalReport(RecordOutputMgr*)’:
coverageFile.cpp:100:46: error: ‘asprintf’ was not declared in this scope
   asprintf(&depthPctString, "%0.7f", depthPct);

Comment: I tried looking for asprintf, but found 0 matches! Appreciate your help.

Comment: `asprintf` is declared inside headers. It should be inside `stdio.h`. The `not declared in this scope` means that the compiler invocation is restricting the visibility of the declaration. Usually it is due to a `-std=c99` or similar. Check the full logs for hint